# Setting "$PATH" environment for Unix "which" command

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, bashrc, paths

I am trying to run two chemistry programs together that need the PATH environment changed in order to find one another. The manual says:

> Under the UNIX operating systems, R.E.D. looks for the "GAMESS", "Gaussian" and "RESP" binaries and scripts using the "which" UNIX command. Thus, one should update the "$PATH" environment variable.

The binaries and files of interest are `gamess.0n.x`, `rungms`, and `ddikick.x` and are all located in `/home/david/Bin/red/RED-III.52-Tools-Files`. Following the advice found in parts of other threads I did the following:

1. Opened the bashrc with `gedit ~/.bashrc`
2. Added the line `PATH=$PATH:/home/david/Bin/red/RED-III.52-Tools-Files`
3. Ran the software

The output of the program, which I will include below, suggests that the "which" command was unable to locate the binary. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
                 * Software checking *
gamess.0n.x  (n = 0->9)                 [ NOT FOUND ]
rungms                                  [ NOT FOUND ]
ddikick.x                               [ NOT FOUND ]
resp                                    [ NOT FOUND ]
ERROR: Some program(s) cannot be executed
```

---

As a note, I found a similar issue on the program's forum (the only difference is they are using gaussian instead of gamess) but I have such an elementary understanding of PATHs and the "which" function that it is difficult to understand. Hopefully, the example is helpful.

> I Am getting the following error. Can someone help?
>
> ```
> * Software checking * 
> gaussian [ NOT FOUND ] 
> resp [ NOT FOUND ]
> ```
>
> You need to set up your .bashrc file if you use bash shell or .cshrc 
>   if you use tcsh/csh.
>
> Here is a part of my .cshrc:
>
> ```
> ------------------------------------------ 
> setenv SOFT /usr/local 
> setenv AMBERHOME /usr/local/amber10 
> setenv GAMESS_SCR /Big-disk/0QM_SCR 
> setenv GAUSS_SCRDIR /Big-disk/0QM_SCR 
> setenv g03root /usr/local 
> source /usr/local/g03/bsd/g03.login 
> set path = ($path $AMBERHOME/exe $SOFT/g03 $SOFT/gamess $SOFT/firefly)  
> ------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> If I use the "which" UNIX command, I get:
>
> ```
> [fyd_at_lynx ~]$ which g03 
> /usr/local/g03/g03 
> [fyd_at_lynx ~]$ which resp 
> /usr/local/amber8/exe/resp
> ```

Comment: Have you restarted the shell (e.g. closing and reopening the terminal) or manually sourced the changed file by running `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I thought that was the problem at first too. I tried closing and reopening the terminal and when that didn't work I tried restarting my computer.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and include the outputs of `which gamess.0n.x rungms ddikick.x`, `echo $PATH` and `ls -l /home/david/Bin/red/RED-III.52-Tools-Files`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is incorrect. `/home/david/Bin/red/RED-III.52-Tools-Files` is the source of the RED ESP program that is looking for GAMESS.

Instead, add the `PATH=$PATH:/home/david/Bin/gamess` to your bashrc. The path that was added to your bashrc file was essentially telling the program where to find itself.